# filtering and transposing the dataframe in python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I made a `csv` file using pandas and trying to use it as input for the next step. when I open the file using pandas it will look like this example:

example:

```
   Unnamed: 0  Class_Name Probe_Name small_example1.csv  small_example2.csv  small_example3.csv
0           0  Endogenous       CCNO                                  196                                    32                                    18
1           1  Endogenous        MYC                                  962                                   974                                  1114
2           2  Endogenous      CD79A                                  390                                   115                                   178
3           3  Endogenous      FSTL3                                   67                                   101                                   529
4           4  Endogenous       VCAN                                  943                                   735                                  9226
```

I want to make a plot, to do so, I have to change the data structure.
1- I want to remove Unnamed column
2- then I want to make a data frame for a heatmap. to do so I want to use these columns "`probe_name`", "`small_example1.csv`", "`small_example2.csv`" and "`small_example3.csv`" 
3- I also want to transpose the data frame.
here is the expected output:

```
Probe_Name  CCNO    MYC CD79A   FSTL3   VCAN
small_example1.csv  196 962 390 67  943
small_example1.csv  32  974 115 101 735
small_example1.csv  18  1114    178 529 9226
```

I tied to do that using the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
result = df.transpose()
```

but it does not return what I want to get. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: What does it return then?

Answer (score 1):

```
df.drop(['Unnamed: 0','Class_Name'],axis=1).set_index('Probe_Name').T
```

Result:

```
Probe_Name          CCNO   MYC  CD79A  FSTL3  VCAN
small_example1.csv   196   962    390     67   943
small_example2.csv    32   974    115    101   735
small_example3.csv    18  1114    178    529  9226
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion:

Changes 1 & 2 can be tackled in one go:

```
df = df.loc[:, ["Probe_Name", "small_example1.csv", "small_example2.csv", "small_example3.csv"]] # This only retains the specified columns
```

In order for change 3 (transposing) to work as desired, the column  `Probe_Name` needs to be set as your index:

```
df = df.set_index("Probe_Name", drop=True)
df = df.transpose()
```

Comment: I am getting this error: /home/behzad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1494: FutureWarning: 
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.

See the documentation here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike
  return self._getitem_tuple(key)

Comment: and the values for probe_Name are NaN

Comment: ah, I misspelt "probe_name", it's supposed to be "Probe_Name". Edited the code accordingly